# Keras: Get the max values from a model output in a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Not really sure whats the best way to title this question, but I would like to process the output from a model as an input to another layer.  I am currently doing that below, but would like to update the information a little.  I simplified the model for simplicity.  Lets say we take an input of `5x5` with `9` channels and its outputs are a `5x5` with `6` channels and `5x5` with `2` channels.

My problem is I would like to process the `model_output1`, and get the max values in each channels, and just have 1's and 0's (as one of the input to the second model).

For example, lets say we have a 2x2 with 3 channels for simplicity.

```
[[[0, 1],
  [9, 3]]

 [[2, 5],
  [5, 4]]

 [[4, 2],
  [8, 7]]]
```

I would like to convert this to just 0s and 1s, where 1 depict the max value with respect to the channel axis.  So for the example above, I would like to get:

```
[[[0, 0],
  [1, 0]]

 [[0, 1],
  [0, 0]]

 [[1, 0],
  [0, 1]]]
```

I tried to convert the `model_output1` to a numpy array with `.eval()` or `.numpy()` but I keep getting errors on it.  I am using `tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0`.  If i can convert it to numpy, I know how I could do it with numpy.

Another solution is to just have 2 separate models. Where I can get `model_output1` using .predict, then manipulate that to get what I want and input it to the second model.  But not sure if thats as efficient.

So in summary, how could I manipulate the tensor `model_output1` to be in the format that I desire?  Is it possible to do it using some `tf.math` functions, without converting it to numpy arrays?  If not, how can I convert it to numpy arrays without throwing any errors? Or is my best bet to have 2 different models, and just manipulate the first output after .predict and process it to be the input I want?

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Input
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_model():
    model_input = Input(shape=(5, 5, 9))

    input_hidden = Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(model_input )
    model_output1 = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(input_hidden)

    input_hidden2 = concatenate(inputs=[model_input, model_output1], axis=3)
    model_output2 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(input_hidden2 )

    model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=[model_output1 , model_output2 ])

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))

    return model
```

Model Summary:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 5, 5, 9)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 5, 5, 8)      656         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 5, 5, 6)      54          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 5, 5, 15)     0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 5, 5, 2)      32          concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 742
Trainable params: 742
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess simply, your question is given a layer output with shape (B, m, n, c), design a small module which gives me the output with the same shape but everything in the tensor will be 0 or 1 (based on your criteria). The unnecessary model part can be ignored completely.

You can use all the `tensorflow` backend functions in your model. Here's a simple module that I designed:

1. the input layer is (2, 2, 3)
2. take the max of the input across the channel (axis = -1), which gives me output shape (2,2)
3. expand the dimension of the max output and concatenate to get a matrix of the same shape as the input (2, 2, 3)
4. then, we add +1 to the input and subtract the concatenated max tensor from that.
5. it will give us a tensor of same shape as input (2,2,3) but every position where there is the max of the channel will now contain 1 and every other value will be either - or 0.
6. finally, we apply `relu` activation to get the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

ip = Input((2,2,3))
mx = tf.keras.backend.max(ip, axis = -1)
a1 = tf.expand_dims(mx, -1)
cat = Concatenate(axis = -1)([a1, a1, a1])
ip_add1 = tf.math.add(ip, 1)
sub = Subtract()([ip_add1, cat])
neg2zero = Activation('relu')(sub)

model = Model(ip, neg2zero)

x = np.transpose(np.array([
  [[0, 1],
  [9, 3]],

 [[2, 5],
  [5, 4]],

 [[4, 2],
  [8, 7]]], dtype = np.float32)) # your matrix need to be transposed as it had wrong order

print(x)
print(x.shape)
y = model(x)
print(y)
```

Out:

```
[[[0 2 4]
  [9 5 8]]

 [[1 5 2]
  [3 4 7]]]
(2, 2, 3)
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 2, 2, 3) for input Tensor("input_20:0", shape=(None, 2, 2, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (2, 2, 3).
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 0. 1.]
  [1. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: When I try your solution with 'from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Subtract, Activation' declaration, I get an error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' in line: 'model = Model(ip, neg2zero)'

Comment: Please use `tensorflow.keras`, `keras` has many bugs already and will be obsolete soon after getting merged with `tf`. Also, you clearly mentioned, you're using `tensorflow 2.0`.

Comment: Ah okay, I didnt know that.  That did fix that issue, sorry for the confusion.  But now I am getting an error: ValueError: Inconsistent values for attr 'T' DT_INT32 vs. DT_FLOAT while building NodeDef 'Max' using Op<name=Max; signature=input:T, reduction_indices:Tidx -> output:T; attr=keep_dims:bool,default=false; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]; attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]>' for line 'y = model(x)'

Comment: I ran my code on google colab, which has tensorflow version `2.2.0-rc4`, you're getting error for running my exact code?

Comment: Yea, I just copied your code, plus the imports.  I am using tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0

Comment: @user1179317, yes I was able to reproduce the error in tensorflow 2.1, I fixed the code. Check now.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the quick response.  It works!